# Create Table of replacement rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, broken-code, databases

I want to create a table of replacement rules.

```
g[a_, b_] := a -> b

t1 = Table[10 i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 3}]
t2 =  Table[ i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 3}] 

g[  # & @@@ t1, # & @@@ t2 ]
```

The correct output is below:

```
{{11 -> 2, 12 -> 3, 13 -> 4},
 {21 -> 3, 22 -> 4, 23 -> 5},
 {31 -> 4, 32 -> 5, 33 -> 6},
 {41 -> 5, 42 -> 6, 43 -> 7},
 {51 -> 6, 52 -> 7, 53 -> 8}}
```

Instead I am getting:

```
  {11, 21, 31, 41, 51} -> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Which shows two concepts I am still trying to wrap my mind around how to accomplish in *Mathematica*.

In a 2-d list how to you select each row, and then perform an operation on each element of that row ( in this case take that element and make a rule replacment a -> b).  Then iterate through every row.

Comment: `SetAttributes[g, Listable]`

Comment: Moreover, `# & @@@ t1` is effectively `First /@ t1` so why do you expect all the values?

Comment: @Kuba I couldn't figure out how to get all the values.  2D lists in mathematica are still a challenge for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest solution is to set attribute `Listable` for `g`:

```
SetAttributes[g, Listable]
g[a_, b_] := a -> b

t1 = Table[10 i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 3}];
t2 = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 3}];

g[t1, t2]
```

> ```
> {{11 -> 2, 12 -> 3, 13 -> 4}, {21 -> 3, 22 -> 4, 23 -> 5}, 
>  {31 -> 4, 32 -> 5, 33 -> 6}, {41 -> 5, 42 -> 6, 43 -> 7}, 
>  {51 -> 6, 52 -> 7, 53 -> 8}}
> ```

Alternatively:

```
MapThread[Rule, {t1, t2}, 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

Of course in this case it would be better if you could write a single `Table` expression:

```
t3 = Table[10 i + j -> i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{11 -> 2, 12 -> 3, 13 -> 4},
>  {21 -> 3, 22 -> 4, 23 -> 5},
>  {31 -> 4, 32 -> 5, 33 -> 6},
>  {41 -> 5, 42 -> 6, 43 -> 7},
>  {51 -> 6, 52 -> 7, 53 -> 8}}
> ```

If not you can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) with a third parameter:

```
MapThread[g, {t1, t2}, 2] === t3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If none of the elements are themselves lists you can use the `Listable` property as Kuba showed.  Otherwise `MapThread` is more general.

For completeness you could also write:

```
Thread /@ Thread[g[t1, t2]]
```